# Mapping Realm objects to a Dict via Swift map

Tags: swift, object, dictionary, realm

I have two (Realm.io) objects like this:

```
class Parent: Object {
    var title = “”
    var children = List<Child>()

    var dict: [String: Any] {
        print(“Dict 1”)
        return ([“title”: self.title, “children”: self.children.map{ $0.dict }])
    }
}

class Child: Object {
    var name = “”

    var dict: [String: Any] {
        print(“Dict 2”)
        return ([“name”: self.name])
    }
}
```

I’m trying to convert them both to a dictionary in one swoop like this:

```
let parent_dict = parent.dict
```

It works fine for “title” and other such Parent attributes, but never actually goes to map the Child class object.

The output for the above example would be just: `Dict 1`

Comment: Without testing this with a Realm, I converted `List<Child>` to `[Child]` and it works fine. Do you know that the children property actually includes any Child instances?

Comment: Other issues aside, you need to define your `List` using `let`, and your vars stored in the Realm using `dynamic var`, not just `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you add all the objects to the realm first. The following code works (try it in a playground inside your project):

```
import RealmSwift

class Parent: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
    var children = List<Child>()

    var dict: [String: Any] {
        print("Dict 1")
        return (["title": self.title, "children": self.children.map{ $0.dict }])
    }
}

class Child: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""

    var dict: [String: Any] {
        print("Dict 2")
        return (["name": self.name])
    }
}

let p1 = Parent(); p1.title = "John"
let c1 = Child(); c1.name = "Pam"
let c2 = Child(); c2.name = "Andrew"
let c3 = Child(); c3.name = "Barrack"

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(p1)
    realm.add([c1, c2, c3])

    p1.children.append(objectsIn: [c1, c2, c3])
}

print(p1.dict)
```

After running the code the console will read:

```
Dict 1
["title": "John", "children": Swift.LazyMapRandomAccessCollection<RealmSwift.List<Child>, Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>>(_base: List<Child> (
    [0] Child {
        name = Pam;
    },
    [1] Child {
        name = Andrew;
    },
    [2] Child {
        name = Barrack;
    }
), _transform: (Function))]
```